# Server side data processing in android

Tags: android, tomcat

So far I have been working on building this Android app and was storing all data into phones internal memory..Now i want to move every thing to server so that all the data will get stored on server and receive from server. I want to do it on Apache (tomcat) server. can somebody please guide me how I can start this.Some nice tutorials or any help would be great.!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a web service and send requests to it from your android application. 
Here is a nice tutorial

> http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.com/2011/09/connecting-to-remote-mysql-database.html

EDIT: another tutorial

> http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-mysql-client.html

Comment: Thanks..This is nice tutorial...But I want to use file structure instead of using database for the data..How can I achieve that?

Comment: By File structure I mean create folder on server per user and store all the data inside that folder

Comment: You might need to take a look at  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html and  http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/08/upload-file-to-remote-server-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

install apache tomcat on your server, use a sql database and use json for communication.
For the rest: Do you know google? Its a nice search engine. You find it at google.com

I like this book for beginning with servlets / tomcat:

http://www.amazon.de/Head-First-Servlets-Bryan-Basham/dp/0596516681/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1353091543&sr=8-2

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I know I can google this question and collect all kind of information from there...I posted it here cause I wanted to go in a right direction and can have different opinions.